# Probability simplex: clarifying dimensions.

Tags: probability, geometry, simplex

I have some doubts about the notion of probability simplex.
Consider the region
$$
\{(x_1,...,x_K): \sum_{k=1}^K x_k=1 , x_k\geq 0\text{ } \forall k=1,...,K\}
$$

1) Is this called a $(K-1)$-probability simplex?

2) Let $K=2$. Then, the graphical representation of the $1$-probability simplex is in the picture below. It is a line segment. Correct?
[image]

3) Let $K=3$.Then, I guess that the graphical representation of the $2$-probability simplex is in the picture below. It is a tetrahedron. Correct?

[image]

4) If all the above is correct, I'm confused on why we are going from a line segment to a 3-D object. In fact, if I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Examples), then the 2-D simplex is a triangle.

Could you help me to clarify?

Comment: As for 3): check your definition. Is $(0,0,0)$ in the 3-simplex?

Comment: Putting it simply, everything you have written is correct. The definition presented is called $K-1$-simplex, as it need $K-1$ arguments to form. For example the last term of sum is eventually derived from the other $K-1$. Line is indeed an object of dimension 1. Rotate it if you need. )). The triangle is indeed of dimension 2 (it is a part of surface). Again Rotate it if you need.))

Comment: @GoodBoy thanks, my second picture is wrong then.

Comment: When $K=3$, it should be a triangle, I guess. Then, I'm confused on the following: take $K=3$; draw the 2-simplex, which is a triangle; any point in the triangle is defined by two coordinates $(x,y)$; where is $z$? Instead when $K=2$, the line segment is exhaustive because the coordinate of each point gives both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $z= 1-x-y$. It's enough, i think. Otherwise you can define  $(K-1)$-simplex like this $\{(x_{1}, ... , x_{K-1}) : \sum_{i=1}^{K-1}x_{i} \leq 1, x_{i} \geq 0 \}$

Comment: I recommend the diagrams in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81136/the-meaning-of-representing-the-simplex-as-a-triangle-surface-in-dirichlet-distr) Q&A for a better intuition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess that the $2$-probability simplex is the whole tetrahedron is not correct.  The set of points $\ (x,y,z)\ $ such that $\ x+y+z=1\ $, and $\ 0\le x$, $0\le y, 0\le z\ $, is just the *single plane face* of the tetrahedron passing through the points $\ (1,0,0),\ (0,1,0),$ and $\ (0,0,1)\ $, that is, a *2-dimensional* object.

Comment: Thanks, looking at my picture, is it the front face of the tetrahedron?

Comment: @TEX Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarise my thoughts below.

1) I only encountered these in the setting of topology: In which setting it would be called "the $(K-1)$-standard simplex."

**N.B.** As for the rest, you should note that the $(K-1)$ is referring to the **dimension**, i.e. "$K$ variables and one constraint".

2) You're absolutely right!

3) This is not correct! The angle you chose to draw the picture I think has mislead you. You're right in that the dimension, ($K-1$) should be equal to $2$!

4) Your confusion is understandable: you should convince yourself that it is the triangle with vertices $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$!

Indeed, you may notice for all $n \ge 1$ that each of the "faces" of the $n$-simplex are in fact copies of the $n-1$ simplex!

Answer (score 0):

To find out the probability simplex you should think of the convex hull, which is the set of all convex combinations of points.
Now for K=3, think of convex combination of e1, e2, and e3. If we think of it from the origin (0, 0, 0) we know that it forms a triangle, just 1 face of tetrahedron, just like the hypotenuse of a right triangle.